# Insert a an array into an SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have code to get installed applications off the computer and want to add it into an SQL table.
how do I do this and keep formatting ?

I would like it to be app1 newline app2 newline app3

```
ArrayOfApps = GetApps();

USE ComputerData INSERT INTO InstalledApps ( Apps ) VALUES (ArrayOfApps);"
```

Comment: Don't do this. Insert into separate rows and format only for presentation.

Comment: How do you suggest? My table is something like "computername, osname, installedapps" do you suggest multiple tables or something?

Comment: Hold only one piece of data per row/column. Probably the best is to remove "installedapps" and add a second table with (idoffirsttable, installedapp) which contains one row per program. Second best alternative would be inserting multiple rows, with the same name/os and different program. In any case, the formating is delegated to the visual layer.

Comment: Use a Table Valued Parameter, or `SqlBulkCopy`

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your query like this

```
USE ComputerData 
INSERT INTO InstalledApps ( Apps ) VALUES (ArrayOfApps[0]),(ArrayOfApps[1]),(ArrayOfApps[2]);"
```

Comment: If I was to display this afterwards would it appear like this : app1app2app3 or app1, app2, app3